# CefSharp WPF and MVVM?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, cefsharp

I am using CefSharp for WPF. I want to use it in MVVM architecture. Unfortunately there is a problem.
In the view I have:

```
<ContentPresenter Content="{Binding Browser}"
                  HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                  VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
```

In ViewModel I put a new object into `Browser`:

```
var settings = new CefSharp.Settings
{
    PackLoadingDisabled = true,
}
if (CefSharp.CEF.Initialize(settings))
{
    int counter = 0;
    this.Browser = new WebView();
}
```

Unfortunately I cannot Load any URL at any point after that. It says `Browser not initialized` and actually the `IsBrowserInitialized` property (in `Browser`) is `false`.

That is weird because in test app, not MVVM, where I used same code to instantiate the WebView it works. Only difference is that I programmatically added the Browser to a Grid as it was not MVVM.

Anyone got the CefSharp in WPF MVVM app? Any ideas?

Thanks

EDIT:
I have noticed in test non-MVVM app, that the `IsBrowserInitialized` property is set to false until window constructor ends the job.

Comment: I managed to make it work, but there a weird problem. When I click on the page inside the WebView - it makes selection from the top of the page to the point I clicked. Why?

Answer (score 8):

CefSharp version 1 is not very well suited for MVVM at the moment, unfortunately. Luckily, in CefSharp 3 I have tried to make it more "MVVM-aware" so you don't have to do a lot of hacks. See the [CefSharp.Wpf.Example code](https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/tree/master/CefSharp.Wpf.Example) there and you will (hopefully) see what I mean.

The way to get it working with CefSharp version 1.xx is to set up a `PropertyChanged` event handler. Once the `IsBrowserInitialized` property gets set to true, you can then do your work. Like this:

```
    webView.PropertyChanged += OnWebViewPropertyChanged;

    // ...

    private void OnWebViewPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        switch (e.PropertyName)
        {
            case "IsBrowserInitialized":
                if (webView.IsBrowserInitialized)
                {
                    webView.Load("http://some/url");
                }
                break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: That example link you gave is broken.

Answer (score -1):

I appreciate it's an old question and possibly answered elsewhere, but given the succinct title google may send you here (it did for me!)

The underlying ChromiumWebBrowser is *very* MVVM friendly..

- Create the control in xaml for binding as a source/destination amongst your other controls.  e.g. bind back button.
- AND optionally create the control in your view model (aka MVVM), e.g. more complicated browser management such as invoking js, hooking up events, etc.

Example..

```
<cefSharp:ChromiumWebBrowser name="browser" WebBrowser="{Binding WebBrowser, Mode=OneWayToSource}"
 Address="{Binding Address, Mode=TwoWay}"
 RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode="{Binding ElementName=scalingModeComboBox, Path=SelectedItem}" />
```